# Debugging the code of an external library in Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using SBT and IntellijIdea to run a project. I basically need to develop a module that relies on some other library to do its job. However, I want to "see" the control flow on the library while I'm debugging my project. That is:

```
-> callToLibrary(...)
```

While debugging, I want to be able to enter this call and see the code of the external library. What are the configurations on Intellij Idea and SBT in order to do so?

**Specifications**

In order to be more precise assume my project has the following structure:

```
project-name
-> .idea
-> project[project-name-build]
-> src -> main
       -> test
-> target
-> build.sbt
-> External Libraries
```

Say I have the sources of my external library in some file stored in the path written in `directory`. Say this sources files are just a project cloned from Github.

What would be the structure needed in the SBT file and the configuration in Intellij Idea in order to get the project working (not complaining with the imports) and being able to debug the project and the external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `transitiveClassifiers := Seq("sources")` in build.sbt, so that all your libraries have sources downloaded. Then all you need to do is debug your app as you normally would. When stepping into library code, the source will be displayed. Additionally, IntelliJ will decompile a class for you if source is not available. Something like this in your `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]](
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
  // ...
, transitiveClassifiers := Seq("sources")
) 

lazy val root = 
  Project( 
    id = "some_name"
  , base = file(".")
  , aggregate = Seq( ... )
  )
  .enablePlugins(...)
  .settings( commonSettings: _* )
)
```

Comment: If your dependencies are from Github, reference them in your build.sbt instead of manually downloading the JARs. Then sbt will download the source as well.

Comment: See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html for dependency management

Comment: On the repository sites (e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/) all three components are shown (group, artifact, version)

Comment: Documentation at https://github.com/epfl-lara/inox shows how you can import Inox. Try to use similar expressions for Welder, because they are hosted in the same place and probably configured in a similar way

Comment: Or: clone Welder and build it using sbt, and make it publish a JAR and a source JAR locally to your machine. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html Once you have built Welder into a JAR, you can add it to your project. Then in IntelliJ, right-click on the Welder JAR and specify the location of the source code.